# Opening a local pdf file in iframe with javascript

Tags: javascript, iframe

I am using the below code to open a pdf file but its not working-

```
<iframe src="file:///C:\Users\Downloads\0895custbill08132015.pdf" style="height: 638px;" frameborder="0"></iframe>
```

For a google doc the below code is working fine, I am not sure what is required to open a locally saved doc.

```
<iframe src="http://docs.google.com/gview?url=http://webshire-aioopsss.com/pdfs/sample_contract.pdf&embedded=true" style="height:638px;" frameborder="0"></iframe>
```

Comment: missed the code-
1. iframe src="file:///C:\Users\sd\Downloads\0895custbill08132015.pdf&embedded=true" style="height: 638px;" frameborder="0"

2. iframe src="http://docs.google.com/gview?url=http://aaux-playground.com/pdfs/sample_contract.pdf&embedded=true" style="height:638px;" frameborder="0"

Answer (score 2):

Most browsers won't let you open a locally stored file from a website for security reasons. Typically I will host the file on an IIS server and then retrieve it from there (which is what you're doing when you're retrieving it from googledoc).

Answer (score 0):

You are using backslashes in your `src`. Please change them to slashes

```
<iframe src="file:///C:/Users/Downloads/0895custbill08132015.pdf" style="height: 638px;" frameborder="0"></iframe>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use 
    var pdf = $('\<\object type="application/pdf">');
    pdf.attr('data', "you pdf scr");
append it in your iframe..